# Proxying HTTPS requests with sc-server

Tags: javascript, ssl, https, nginx, sproutcore

I don't seem to be able to proxy an https (SSL) request with sc-server. The server keeps saying REDIRECTING TO, but I get no results whatsoever, because the request gets canceled

I hope there is some configuration possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an option for HTTPS

```
proxy '/path', :to => 'server', :https => true
```